# Why does View A with bottom constraints not move when View B changes

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Button inside a `UIView`. Set up with bottom constraints. Once I change the height of the `UIView`, I expect the Button to move since it has (**equal**) Constraints to the Bottom.

[image]

Bottom Constraints set:

[image]

Button nested inside `UIView`.

[image]

Once I move the UITableView, the following code get's called:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let offset = -scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if offset > 100 {
        bgView.frame.size.height = offset
        bgView.layoutIfNeeded() // not a solution
        getBtn.layoutIfNeeded() // not a solution
    }

    view.bringSubview(toFront: tableView)
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y == -100.0 {
        view.bringSubview(toFront: bgView)
    }
}
```

The Button keeps its position.

[image] [image]

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

As requested:

[image]

Comment: What other constraints are on "Get Btn"? It looks like it's also pinned to the top. You're right, from what you've shown us the button is prioritized to properly be pinned to the bottom of "Bg View".

Comment: no. only height, width and center horizontally, besides bottom

Comment: I pretty much work my constraints in code, so bear with me here. SOmething's doesn't compute (probably for you too) - I'm seeing where BG View is 100 height (and your screenshots show it as such. I'm also seeing only one constraint "tree" node expanded, which I believe to be Bg View, right? If so, can you expand Get Btn?

Comment: sure. provided.

Comment: Don't change height of the `bgView` change its height constraint then it'll work

Comment: @HamzaAnsari please post as answer. that did it. thank you very much. but still weird tho. because it should still stay at the bottom of the views... shouldnt it?

Comment: Wow, that is weird. @Hamza, please post that answer.

Comment: Just as a tip, if you want to show others constraints related to a view, open the left panel and there is an icon for "Show the Size Inspector" which looks like a ruler. With the view selected, all constraints related to that view will be there, without having unrelated ones cluttering around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an IBOutlet for bgView Height Constraint and then change its constant

```
@IBOutlet weak var bgViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

  let offset = -scrollView.contentOffset.y
  if offset > 100 {
     bgViewHeightConstraint.constant = offset
    view.layoutIfNeeded() 
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: any chance to explain? :/

Comment: when you change frame height or width it doesnt change its constraint connected to it and thats what happening in your case if you just change the height, the constraint is still the same thats why your button is not moving with it.

Comment: Why did it stay like it was pinned to the top of things?

Comment: because the bottom constraint breaks... keeping the other constraint. you can also remove the button height for easy option where you won't need any computation.